# Upsource Error: Github Url not Detected when using github enterprise server

Tags: github, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, upsource

Can't figure how to resolve an error when trying to setup upsource on EC2 where everything is fine except when trying to integrate with GitHub.

I simply use ssh for authentication and then input my GitHub url as

```
git@github.<company>.com:<user>/<repo>.git
```

But I get the message:

```
GitHub URL is not detected
```

Also tried https with same result.
It's not that it tries to authenticate; it's not able to parse and recognize the url.

I tried my personal github repo without the enterprise name in the url and that worked fine.
I tried builds 3.0 and 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

> It's not that it tries to authenticate; it's not able to parse and recognize the url.
>   I tried my personal github repo without the enterprise name in the url and that worked fine

That means the [Upsource in-cloud installation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/upsource/3.5/in-cloud-installation.html) expects a github.com url (in "[Creating a GitHub project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/upsource/3.5/creating-a-github-project.html)"), and not a `github.<compny>.com` url when using ssh.

You can see in [issue UP-6585](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/UP-6585) that https urls are preferred (but not always possible for a private GitHub server instance).
ssh should be supported but, as you commented:

> I just installed 3.5 and also unable to use an enterprise ssh url such as `git@github.<company>.com:<user>/<repo>.git` using ssh authentication.

Comment: interesting. okay. that's too bad then. Didn't realize that it wouldn't be possible with a private enterprise repo. Thanks.